# C++ string to C string

Tags: c++, c, string

Consider the following piece of code:

```
void fun (string &str1, string &str2)
{
   const char* cstr;
....
   if(strlen(cstr = (str1+str2).c_str()) < 15)
   {
      // here cstr used
   }
}
```

The condition itself works fine, but in the if-condition body `cstr` contains garbage. Why?

Comment: Why are you using `strlen` when you can use `std::string::length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the `string` in your C++ code is `std::string`.

`str1 + str2` produces a *temporary* `std::string` object. You invoke the `c_str()` method on it, and you get a C-style string pointer to the data of this *temporary* `std::string` object.

When the temporary `std::string` goes out of scope and is destroyed, the `cstr` raw C-style pointer is left dangling, pointing to invalid memory.

If you need to work on the concatenated string `str1 + str2`, I would suggest you safely store it in a *non*-temporary `std::string` object, e.g.:

```
std::string s = str1 + str2;
// Work with s
if (s.length() < 15) {
    // Use s here
    ...
}
```

Note also that I invoked the `std::string::length()` method instead of the C function `strlen()`. You can use the `std::string::size()` method, as well.

In general, in C++ code, you should use convenient string *classes* (like `std::string`), instead of C-style raw string pointers.

Answer (score 9):

In this expression:

```
cstr = (str1+str2).c_str()
```

you are taking a pointer to the *temporary* string `str1 + str2`. This temporary dies at the end of the expression, and so you have undefined behaviour when you try to read from `cstr` inside the if-body.